# Pdf files are not getting updated after docusign

Tags: caching, browser-cache, docusignapi

We are using Embedded signing of DocuSign REST API to e-sign files.To sign a file, we upload the required file to our web app and then display it a viewer in the browser. This file can be signed immediately or later.

What is happening is that when the file is signed and the process is completed, we return to the same file view but the updated file is not reflected. Only when we refresh page like 3-4 times, it shows the sign on the file.

This issue comes only for files that were uploaded and signed later. For a fresh file which is uploaded and signed immediately, we get the updated file view.

It appears that all the browsers cache files (not HTML page, but the embedded files). The recommended solutions suggest to either add a parameter in the request when file is reloaded after signing- but this works only intermittently. The other is to rename the file so that the browser picks the updated file. But renaming file is not an option for us.

Is there some other alternative? Have any other DocuSign API users ever faced something similar? (I believe this issue would not come if you use email request mode for e-signing)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There have been no similar reports from anyone... I am not discounting yours necessarily but when you just write up something about your web app I could think of a few things that your web app could be doing out of sequence to see this behavior.

The first common mistake with embedded signing that comes to mind is this.  In general embedded signing requires several steps (1) login call (2) create envelope (3) get the view of the recipients.

Most of the people put that logic in the controller code behind a web page so when they come back it goes through the same sequence.  I understand that your page has some logic to maybe guard against it, but ideally on the "viewing" you should only call (3) - getting the view.  If you somehow end up calling (2) again - you will see the signing sequence all over.

That's the most common mistake.  However I do not want to discount your report.  In order to actually get to the bottom of it you should post the web service call traces (XML for SOAP / JSON for REST) and show exactly what your app is doing.

Hope this helps.

-mb // i work for docusign

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand what you are saying here. However, the process we are following for 'viewing' is to give the file view url as the callback url in the embedded signing. So we are not going through the entire process. This is what we understood as the purpose of the callback url in the embedded signing. Is there some other way of rendering the singed document other than giving it in the callback url?

Comment: Why are you giving the recipient view URL as the callback url?  By callback you mean the returnURL right?  You shouldn't be doing that, and that might be causing your out of sync issues.  You only use the recipient view URL token to access the envelope once, sign or decline to sign, and then get redirected to the return URL.  Please use [this api walkthrough](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning) as an example